# How to make this vertical coverflow animation with collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, coverflow

I am trying to build the vertical coverflow animation like this but not found any suitable lib using collection view. if someone know how to build it or any lib i would really appreciate.

[image]

slow motion

[image]

Comment: why are you using collectionView?? are there more images or only 2?

Comment: post some code if you have any ideas or what you end's up with.

Comment: i have used cfcoveflow to implement this but thats not provide the ability to change the bottom image and label data

Comment: You don't mean the navigation do you? You mean the animation right? If it's the animations is there a gif that does it slower? It's kinda hard to see what's going on

Comment: yeah, it's animation, ok let me try to make it slow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly recommend using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), it has a predefined set of animations, however, you can create your own custom animations using `iCarouselTypeCustom` and the delegate method `carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:`

It is very well documented and has loads of examples. However, if you still have any questions regarding how to use it just let me know.

**Update:**
Here's a [working project](https://github.com/bsameh/FullScreenCarouselExample) I created in order to demonstrate how to use iCarousel to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement this with little example

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a working project that demonstrates how to use iCarousel to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement this with native collectionview

Comment: @Retro: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You can send your contracting work to Bassem Sameh.